# Запуск CSS-анимации с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация

Добрый день.
Реализовано переключение языков, как показано на картинках. Необходимо добавить плавную анимацию к появлению скрытых языков при клике.
[image: Переключение языков]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function openLangs() {
  var el = document.getElementById("drop-lang");
  if (el.style.display == "none" || !el.style.display) {
    el.style.display = "inline";
    el.classList.add("slideRight");
  } else {
    el.style.display = "none";
    el.classList.remove("slideRight");
  }
}
```

```css
.slideRight {
  animation-name: slideRight;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideRight;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lang" onclick="openLangs()">
  <a class="dropdown-lang"> <img src="img/icons/en.png" alt=""> </a>
</div>
<div id="drop-lang">
  <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/gm.png" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/rus.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

На данный момент стиль с анимацией добавляется, но самой анимации не видно. Как можно запустить анимацию при  изменении свойства display на "inline"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем такие сложности, если можно обойтись минимумом

```js
var el = document.getElementById("drop-lang");
document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0].addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    el.classList.toggle("active");

  })
```

```css
#drop-lang {
  transform: translateX(-1000px);
  transition: transform .5s;
}

#drop-lang.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
  <img width="50" height="35" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/cfb53a44-9ec5-4958-8682-3b51a23324c0/s1200" alt="">
</div>
<div id="drop-lang">
  <img width="265" height="200" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/cfb53a44-9ec5-4958-8682-3b51a23324c0/s1200" alt="">
  <img width="265" height="200" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/cfb53a44-9ec5-4958-8682-3b51a23324c0/s1200" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это уже ближе, чем мои попытки) Но в первоначальном состоянии языки должны быть скрыты, поэтому и пыталась менять свойство display.  Есть какой грамотный вариант, чтобы спрятать их? https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/1/25/67fd2e0cf348c34c6297dd62741fe14e-full.png

Comment: @Алёна, `display:none; transition`  не срабатывает, по этому у тебя не получалось плавно выводить

Comment: В вашем примере они прячутся за областью видимости, как-то можно спрятать их другим способом? Я прикрепила скрин в прошлом комментарии, они должны "выезжать" из-под активного языка, то есть каким-то образом быть невидны изначально

Comment: Всё, додумалась до overflow: hidden)

Comment: )))))  рад был помочь

Answer (score 0):

Опишите анимацию в отдельном классе, скажем `state-played` и скриптом снимайте\устанавливайте этот класс.

Comment: Посмотрите скрипт, там ведь сейчас так  и написано, как вы предлагаете?